# Initializing an array of char pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to create an array of `char` pointers in different ways, but only the first method works:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(){

 char* a[] = {"hello"};
 // works

 char** b = {"hello"}; 
 // warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 
 // 'char **' with an expression of type 'char [6]' 

 char c[][] = {"hello"};  
 // error: array has incomplete element type 'char []'

 return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2. Since neither element is an array, the C compiler does not recognize the `{"hello"}` syntax as an array, which will cause the code to break. If you do `char** b = a` you can observe that the syntax does in fact work.
3. When working with multidimensional arrays in C, every dimension except the first must be given a length, since the compiler cannot infer it. If you change it to `char c[][6] = {"hello"}` you can observe that it works.

Answer (score 1):

1. This `char* a[];` is an array of `char*`, aka array of `char` pointers.
2. This `char** b;` is a *pointer to* `char*`, or, in other words, a pointer to pointer to `char`. The initializer `{"hello"}` is wrong because its type is "array of `char*`".
3. This `char c[][];` is an invalid declaration. You are declaring an array of arrays of `char`, but you don't specify the size of the subarray. You have to change it to something like `char c[][N];` so that the sub-array has a known size, or even `char c[M][N];` so that you know the entire size. Using the initializer here is OK, but note that it is interpreted as a completely different type than the first.

Correct initializations would be:

1. `char* a[] = {"hello"};`, this will create an array `a` with one element pointing to some memory location chosen by the compiler where the `"hello"` string is stored.
2. `char** b = a;` or `char** b = &a[0];`, this simply creates a pointer to pointer to char, so assigning `a` or `&a[0]` to it is the only reasonable thing here. There could be other applications, but it depends on the case.
3. `char c[][10] = {"hello"};`, this will create an array `c` with one sub-array of size `10` holding the elements `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'}`.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. For example 2, GCC treats `{"hello"}` as `"hello"` due to the typing of `b`, not an array containing `"hello"`.

Answer (score 1):

All of these are incorrect at some extent.

- `a` initializes an array of 1 single pointer `char*`, pointing at the string literal `"hello"`. But since we aren't allowed to modify string literals, this should have been written as `const char* a[] = {"hello"};`.
- `b` attempts to set a pointer-to-a-`char`-pointer to point at a string literal, which is not valid C. A conforming compiler must give you a message saying that the code isn't correct.
- `c` is nonsense syntax, we cannot declare arrays of arrays with no dimensions known. Only the left-most dimension can be left blank, for the compiler to set implicitly.